# when I try to add Mongodb gpg - gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found

Tags: mongodb

'Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
After I enter
Download and add the MongoDB GPG key with the following command

wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -
I get the following error.  ""
adminpc@Adm:~$ wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
OK                      ""
tried manually removing using rm as per the solution available in SOF using
'sudo rm "/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home:manuelschneid3r.asc"'
rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home:manuelschneid3r.asc': No such file or directory
But the above message appears.
ls of /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d shows following files.
adminpc@Adm:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d$ ls
danielrichter2007-ubuntu-grub-customizer.gpg   ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg``
danielrichter2007-ubuntu-grub-customizer.gpg~  ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg

please help in this regard, I need to deploy Mongodb server for educational purpose. I am using UBUNTU22.04 LTS'

Answer (score 0):

**First part**
Ubuntu wants you to separate GPG keys.
Ubuntu doesn’t want you to add all the signature keys in the single /etc/apt/trusted.gpg file. It suggests using a separate file that are located in the /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d directory.

You should add the GPG keys to the system in the proper way.

- Downloading the keys and checking if it is armored or not
- If the file is armored, it needs to be dearmored in binary format.

your GPG key should not be ‘armored’. It should be in binary format (if you try to read it, it shows gibberish) like this

```
ay`�����?o;���Lh����҇�^j?�,4�@8�Xh�]�j�F��Q��W�ă|,%C�n��nG�t���׺���b%/Ka����i���
```

- And then the dearmored key is added to its own file under /usr/share/keyrings directory
- The location of the key file is added to the sources list file of the repository

To add the key of some repository in /usr/share/keyrings directory you should do the following:

```
curl -sS https://someURL.gpg | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/spotify.gpg
```

**The next part**
Normally, the content of the sources list file are like this:

```
deb URL_of_the_repo stable non-free
```

You should edit it and add the location of the key file like this:

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/key-file.gpg] URL_of_the_repo stable non-free
```

This way, you are linking the package to a specific key. Now, this key cannot be used to download any other package. No more cross-signing.

You should modified the command this way so that the sources list also contains the signed by information:

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/someproduct.gpg] http://repository.someproduct.com stable non-free" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/someproduct.list
```

Please also see the following URL for details: https://itsfoss.com/apt-key-deprecated/